# Gson and only concentrate on inner object

Tags: java, gson

Ok I have a json coming in that looks like this:

```
{count:xxx, important:[{...}]}
```

All I care about is the important object.  Is there anything I can do with a custom deserializer or anything where I can just have GSON deserialize that important json object?

Also the way I want the deserialized object to look is like this:

```
List<Important> = Gson.fromJson(arg0, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Important>>(){}.getType() );
```

Comment: Having done some recent work the Gson, I just bit the bullet and created all the objects down to the ones that I needed. You can leave out field names, and those objects will just be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`JsonParser`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html) class from the Gson library to read it as a JsonObject. Then, pull out the inner object you need and use Gson to fill your java class with it.

Example:

```
Reader jsonReader =
                new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(getIStream("myFile.json")));
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject top = parser.parse(jsonReader).getAsJsonObject();

JsonElement importantEl = top.get("important");

//Parse the important element into whatever structure you're creating
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<Important> important 
    = Gson.fromJson(importantEl, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Important>>(){}.getType() );
```

Comment: Shouldn't `important` be `el`? I wonder how this work - does it create a json tree?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I was pulling in some code I had written for a project I'm working on. Yes, the JsonObject is a parsed version of the top level json tree, the JsonElement type can represent either a json array or json object. Gson knows how to read it and convert it into the class type you pass in

Comment: What you have make sense, but it will ruin my generic class, so I will work around it some other way...

Comment: Hmm? You can still parse with Gson into your POJO.. I edited my code to take your line.